# загрузка html частей кода ajax ом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Проблема в том что когда подгружаю гугл капчу (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/) на основную страницу, виджет капчи не появляется? почему так происходит? и как сделать правильно?

вот этот код загружается ajax:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: какие шаги вы проделывали? просто вставка html кода в страницу ничего вам не даст. Нужно подключать библиотеки/скрипты. Получить ключ API

Comment: ключ естественно есть, и в основную страницу подключен скрипт `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>`